# Git: commiting only some changes to master

Tags: git

I'm working on a development branch which differs quite extensively from the master branch. I have a number of changes that I want to commit to master, but I definitely can't merge the branches.

How should I do this?

Comment: Are your changes committed already, or not yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`git cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html).

It allows you to pull selected commits from one branch to another.